# SQL Query becomes incredibly slow when ordering empty set

Tags: mysql, sql

I have an SQL query that takes lots of time to evaluate because it is operating on a very big dataset. When trying to improve the execution time I found out the following:

When executing the following query the MySQL server takes a lot of time (up to 100secs)

```
SELECT some_data 
FROM   table 
       INNER JOIN anothertable 
               ON ( table.value = 
                               anothertable.value ) 
WHERE  ( table.parent = 56521 
         AND table.date >= 
             '2016-10-19 08:37:45.606947' ) 
ORDER  BY table.date DESC 
LIMIT  1
```

So I guessed that it's the sorting part of the query that takes so much execution time and I manually removed to sorting to see the differences in the execution:

```
SELECT some_data 
FROM   table 
       INNER JOIN anothertable 
               ON ( table.value = 
                               anothertable.value ) 
WHERE  ( table.parent = 56521 
         AND table.date >= 
             '2016-10-19 08:37:45.606947' ) 
LIMIT  1
```

The query above takes 0.45 secs and leads to an empty query set.

I came to the conclusion that my query orders the WHOLE data set before evaluating the WHERE-Clause. How should I form the query in order to prevent that behaviour? Why does this behaviour show up?

These are the EXPLAIN Tables for the slow and the fast query:

```
Slow
+----+-------------+-------+------------+--------+------------------------------------------+------------------+---------+------------------------------+------+----------+-------------+
    | id | select_type | table | partitions | type   | possible_keys                            | key              | key_len | ref                          | rows | filtered | Extra       |
    +----+-------------+-------+------------+--------+------------------------------------------+------------------+---------+------------------------------+------+----------+-------------+
    |  1 | SIMPLE      | A     | NULL       | index  | PRIMARY,D4b797d14e515242e7251754c57b7701 | date             | 5       | NULL                         | 1325 |     0.08 | Using where |
    |  1 | SIMPLE      | B     | NULL       | eq_ref | PRIMARY                                  | PRIMARY          | 4       | value                        |    1 |   100.00 | NULL        |
    +----+-------------+-------+------------+--------+------------------------------------------+------------------+---------+------------------------------+------+----------+-------------+

Fast:
     +----+-------------+-------+------------+--------+------------------------------------------+----------------------------------+---------+------------------------------+------+----------+-------+
    | id | select_type | table | partitions | type   | possible_keys                            | key                              | key_len | ref                          | rows | filtered | Extra |
    +----+-------------+-------+------------+--------+------------------------------------------+----------------------------------+---------+------------------------------+------+----------+-------+
    |  1 | SIMPLE      | A     | NULL       | ref    | PRIMARY,D4b797d14e515242e7251754c57b7701 | D4b797d14e515242e7251754c57b7701 | 4       | const                        | 5175 |   100.00 | NULL  |
    |  1 | SIMPLE      | B     | NULL       | eq_ref | PRIMARY                                  | PRIMARY                          | 4       | value                        |    1 |   100.00 | NULL  |
    +----+-------------+-------+------------+--------+------------------------------------------+----------------------------------+---------+------------------------------+------+----------+-------+
```

Comment: Probably, adding/removing `ORDER BY …` leads to execution plan changing. You should try `EXPLAIN SELECT …` in both cases to see how it differs. Additionally: are `table.parent`, `table.date`, `table.value` and/or `anothertable.value` indexed?

Comment: All of the three fields are indexed.

Comment: Another observation: Not EVERY execution of this query leads to long executions times. Some are executed instantly, some take more time - same query, different values for parents/dates

Comment: Runnig the query with ONLY "Where" OR only "Order" is extremely fast. The combination of both makes it horribly slow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL uses the index on `date` for your first query. It can partially evaluate the `where`-condition (`table.date >= '2016-10-19 08:37:45.606947'`), and if that fits, it will read `parent` from your table (which is relatively slow) to see if it fits as well. It can stop as soon as it finds a result (because of the `order by` and `limit 1`).

Your second query uses the index on `parent` (that is the index with the long name), looks for rows that fits, then reads the `date`-part from your table and check if it fits too. It has to continue until it has checked all rows with the correct `parent`-value (that it finds using the index), and all rows it found have to undergo a filesort, and the newest one will be returned.

(I ommitted that MySQL will have to check/execute the `join` too, but that is the same in both queries).

You obviously have a lot more rows that fit your `date`-condition than your `parent`-condition, so it has to do more relatively slow table lookups, which will take longer.

In this case. Depending on your data, it could actually happen that the first row checked via your index on `date` already fulfills the `parent`-condition, and could stop right there. If it would use the index on `parent`, MySQL would be forced to check all rows with the `parent`-value and then do a filesort. MySQL decided on the basis of some statistical data, it was worth the risk. Well, it chose wrong.

You can do the following:

- `` optimize table `table` `` (the second `table` is your tablename) to update your statistics. This helps sometimes, but usually doesn't (because the statistical data is very limited).
- force MySQL to use the index you know is better (`... FROM table force index (D4b797d14e515242e7251754c57b7701) inner join ...`)
- add the perfect index for your query: a composite index `table(parent, date)` should (not counting potential effects of the `join`) give you an even faster result than your unordered query, and MySQL will use it on its own.

Comment: Thanks for your response. It seems as if your third tip (composite index) solved my issue. The database is incredibly fast since I added the composite index. Thank you very much!